# Library for working with SHA 256 hash in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, cryptography, blackberry-playbook, sha256

I'm looking for an easy way to compute SHA 256 in Action Script on the BlackBerry PlayBook.

I saw the mx.data.crypto.SHA256 class that seems fit for the purpose but it looks like it is not available on the standard PlayBook libraries, or do I need to import any specific SWF?

More generaly, if you know of an easy-to-use cryptographic library for Action Script, I'd welcome that too.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Is `mx.data.crypto.SHA256` the same as `mx.util.SHA256`?  Because the latter comes with flash, and is ridiculously easy to use:  `SHA256.computeDigest(myByteArray)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/

Just download the sources you need and import them where required.

Answer (score 0):

Check maybe http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/benchmark/ is faster.

Comment: Sure, but I still can't find the sources, I guess it's not openSourced, the site doesn't give a lot of information

Answer (score 0):

I also found the Flame library: http://code.google.com/p/flame/

Hash algorithms: MD5, RIPEMD-160, SHA-1, SHA-2 (SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512)

Keyed-hash algorithms: HMAC

Symmetric algorithms: AES, Rijndael, RC4

Asymmetric algorithms: RSA, Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH)